# How to add new row to a vector using struct in C++

Tags: c++

Hello I am having issues with a final project. The objective is to have the user create a form that allows a user to view data, edit data, add data, and save their password data in an encoded format. The program starts with an input file made by the user. The delimiter is ';', and the first char is a "code", then the, site, username, password, and notes follow.

I am very new to vectors, and I am not allowed to use a 2d array, or map.

Thank you for your time.

```
 #include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 30;
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 200;

struct dataRow {
    string site, user, pass, notes;
    string code;
};

string inFileName; //name of inputfile  
string outFileName;
ifstream pathStream;
ofstream outFile;
char inputChar;
int extPosition(1), count = 0,lineNum;

void displayVector(vector<dataRow> inputData);
void viewLineData(vector<dataRow> inputData, int lineNum);
void addNewRow(vector<dataRow> inputData,int& lastRowNum, string site, string user, string pass, string notes);
void editLineData(vector<dataRow> inputData, int& lineNum, string site, string user, string pass, string notes);
void warning();
void cleanBuffer();
bool displayMenu();
int exit();
dataRow descripLine;
int main()
{
    vector<dataRow> inputData;

    string rowDescripin,userin,passin,notesin,sitein;
    string codein,errorMsg;
    int lastRow;
    //add a .txt extension to the file if the user didn't provide an extension
    if (inFileName.size() > 4)
        // If there's a valid extension, it will be in the last 4 positions of the string; Adjust by 1 for 0 offset
        extPosition = inFileName.size() - 4;
    int ext = inFileName.find_last_of(".txt");
    if (!(inFileName.find_last_of(".") == extPosition))
    {
        inFileName += ".txt";
    }

    cout << "\nPlease enter the filename of input file: ";
    cin >> inFileName;

    pathStream.open(inFileName.c_str());
    if (pathStream.fail())
    {
        cerr << inFileName << " failed to open.\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "startup success" << endl;

    }
        getline(pathStream, codein, ';');
        descripLine.code = codein;
        while (!pathStream.eof())
        {
            getline(pathStream, sitein, ';');
            descripLine.site = sitein;

            getline(pathStream, userin, ';');
            descripLine.user = userin;

            getline(pathStream, passin, ';');
            descripLine.pass = passin;

            getline(pathStream, notesin, ';');
            descripLine.notes = notesin;

            inputData.push_back(descripLine);

        }
        displayVector(inputData);
        displayMenu();
        while (cin){
            cin >> inputChar; 
            inputChar = toupper(inputChar);

            //Adjust calculations based on inputCHar
            if (inputChar == 'D')  // Display line descriptions
            {    
                displayVector(inputData);
            }
            else if (inputChar == 'V')  //View line data
            {
                cout << "Enter line number you wish to view: ";
                cin >> lineNum;
                viewLineData(inputData, lineNum);
            }
        /*  else if (inputChar == 'E')  //Edit line Data
            {
                cout << "Enter line number you wish to edit: ";
                cin >> lineNum;
                editLineData(inputData, lineNum);
            }*/
            else if (inputChar == 'A')  //Add line data
            {
                warning();
                lastRow = inputData.size();
                cout << "Enter a line description: ";
                cin >> rowDescripin;

                cout << "Enter a line username: ";
                cin >> userin;

                cout << "Enter a line password: ";
                cin>>passin;

                cout << "Enter notes: ";
                cin>>notesin;

                addNewRow(inputData, lastRow, rowDescripin, userin, passin, notesin);
            }
            /*else if (inputChar == 'S')  //Save and encode file
            {
            }*/
            else if (inputChar == 'X')  //exit program
            {
                exit();
            }
        }
        system("pause");
    }
bool displayMenu()
{
        cout << endl << "           AVAILABLE OPTIONS           " << endl << endl <<
            "D - DISPLAY LINE DESCRIPTIONS" << endl <<
            "V - VIEW LINE DATA" << endl <<
            "E - EDIT LINE DATA" << endl <<
            "A - ADD LINE DATA" << endl <<
            "S - SAVE AND ENCODE FILE" << endl <<
            "X - EXIT PROGRAM" << endl;
        return 0;
}
void viewLineData(vector<dataRow> inputData,int lineNum)
{

        cout << inputData[lineNum].site << endl << inputData[lineNum].user<<endl<<inputData[lineNum].pass <<endl<<inputData[lineNum].notes; 

}
void displayVector(vector<dataRow> inputData)
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputData.size(); i++)
    {   
        cout << left << setw(20) << inputData[i].site ;
    }  
}
void addNewRow(vector<dataRow> inputData, int& lastRowNum, string site, string user, string pass, string notes)
{
    char ans;
    cout << "You have entered:" << endl << site << endl << user << endl << pass << endl << notes<<endl;
    cout << "Is this the data you wish to add (Y/N)? ";
    cin >> ans;
    ans = toupper(ans);
    if (ans == 'Y')
    {
        dataRow tempRow = { site, user, pass, notes };
        inputData.push_back(tempRow);
        cout << inputData.size();
        int num = inputData.size()-1;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputData.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << inputData[i].site << endl << inputData[i].user << endl << inputData[i].pass << endl << inputData[i].notes;
        }

    }
    else if (ans == 'N')
    {
        cout << "ok enter of no";
    }
}

void warning()
{
    cout<< "WARNING: You cannot use semi-colons in these fields. Any semi-colons entered will be removed." << endl;
    return;
}
int exit()
{
    pathStream.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void cleanBuffer()
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(BUFFER_SIZE, '\n');
}
```

Comment: The only question I can see is in the title.  The body of your "question" does not pose an actual question.  If you want to add to a vector use `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `insert` or `emplace`.  If you are expecting `inputData` changes in a function to be visible outside the function, then pass it by reference, not by value.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to make sure that what the program is meant to do was clear. Yes I was expecting the inputData changes in the addNewRow function and then the inputData is visible outside the function. I will try pass by reference right now :)